# Final topology induced by inclusion maps same as the standard topology

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the collection of all compact subsets of $\Bbb R^n$. Prove that the final topology induced on $\Bbb R^n$ by maps $\iota_F :F \in \mathcal{F} \to \Bbb R^n$ is the standard topology.

Let $\mathcal{T}_1$ be the final topology on $\Bbb R^n$. We have that $\mathcal{T}_1=\{U \subset \Bbb R^n \mid \iota^{-1}_F(U) \subset F\}$ where $\iota^{-1}_F(U) \subset F$
is open. However $\mathcal{T}_1=\{U \subset \Bbb R^n \mid \iota^{-1}_F(U) \subset F\}= \{U \subset \Bbb R^n \mid F \cap U \subset F\}$ and $F \cap U \subset F$ is open in $F$ if $F\cap U= F \cap V$ for some $V \subset \Bbb R^n$ open. So we have that $\mathcal{T}_1=\{U \subset \Bbb R^n \mid F \cap V, V \subset \Bbb R^n\}$ where $V \subset \Bbb R^n$ is open. It's not yet very clear why this sould be the standard topology. Is there some other approach to see this?

Comment: Show that the two topologies have the same convergent sequences...

Comment: Look up $k$-space...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Compactly generated Hausdorff space?

Comment: That’s another name for such spaces yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henno Brandsma comments, your final topology on $\mathbb R^n$ is a special case of the so-called $k$-topology which you can define on any space $X$. It is clear that this topology is *finer* than the original topology. If $X$ is locally compact, then it *agrees* with the original topology.

To see this, note that a locally compact $X$ has a basis $\mathcal B$ consisting of open subsets of $X$ all of which are contained in compact subsets of $X$. For $X = \mathbb R^n$ you may take the collection of all open balls.

Now let $U \subset X$ be open in the final topology, i.e. for each compact $F \subset X$ the set $U \cap F$ is open in the subspace $F$. Hence for each $B \in \mathcal B$ the set $U \cap B$ is open in the subspace $B$: Pick a compact $F \subset X$ such that $B \subset F$. Then $U \cap B = (U \cap F) \cap B$ is open in $F \cap B = B$. Since all $B \in \mathcal B$ are open in $X$, all  $U \cap B$  are open in $X$. Thus $U = \bigcup_{B \in \mathcal B} U \cap B$ is open in $X$.